# How would I read the code from the MCU through CUBE-IDE or CUBE-Programmer?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32f1

I have hooked up a STM32F103C8T6 MCU to a programmer and can see some info about it throught the programmer. I was curious on if I could find a way to see the code that is already on it, but not erase it, which is what I am seeing on the programmer. I don't know ifI can/how to hook it up the MCU to CUBE-IDE and go from there either so I am stuck. If that is not possible, are there any resources on how to understand the info, addresses, data, etc. that is displayed through the programmer? I have the data sheet for the MCU but am kinda lost on how to connect and understand the two together.

I'm a beginner at this so I do apologize, I'm trying to learn here. I have looked on youtube and forums but can't find a answer to what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "STM32 ST-LINK Utility" software to connect to your MCU and observe the info un each register.